# Getting value of html element using JSOUP

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have a html like below

```
<div class="test">
<section>
<h4>Education</h4>
**"University1"**
<h4>Residency</h4>
**"resName"**
<h4>certifications</h4>
<ul>
<li>
<strong>Internal med</strong>
<br>
**"Board of secondary"**
</li>
</ul>
<h4>Bio</h4>
**"qualifi"**
<br>
**"hobby"**
</section>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the values in bold using the below code

```
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect("--").userAgent(USER_AGENT).ignoreHttpErrors(true) ;

Document document =connection.get();
for (Element da:document.getElementsByClass("test"))
{ 
System.out.println(da.select("h4"));
}
```

But this is not working as expected.Please assist me to select the highlighted values in bold using jsoup?

Comment: could you please provide output so I can proceed further.

Comment: For the above code I am getting output like <h4>Education</h4>

Comment: But I actually want the below values: **"University1"**  **"resName"**       **"Board of secondary"**    **"qualifi"**    **"hobby"**  .

Comment: So you just want to get all the text elements? Or you just want text that is directly below an <h4> element?

Comment: I want to retrive all the text elements.